# Resize background via CSS

Tags: html, css

I already tried some ways to do it, but still not worked right

Here is a simple code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Convite</title>
<style>
body {
background-image: url("bgg.jpg");   
}

@media screen and (max-width : 480px) {
    background-image: url("bgg.jpg");
    background-size: auto; 480px;


    .1 {height:300px;
        width:480px;
         }  
    .2 {height:107px;
        width:480px;
         }
    .3 {height:34px;
        width:480px;
         }
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<br><br>
    <center>
        <span class="1"><img src="1.png"></span>
        <br><br>
        <span class="2"><img src="2.png"></span>
        <br><br>
        <span class="3"><img src="3.png"></span>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

So I have 4 elements (3 images and 1 background)
The original size of background is 1280 x 720p
I was wondering to resize elements by % but it still not work
The viewport is not working

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Multiple errors found. CSS class name should not start with numbers. Use a-z instead. Also, the syntax in media query (near the `background-image` line) is incorrect. Next, `<br>` should not be used in layout adjustments; use CSS instead. Last, don't make up your own HTML syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS and HTML have tons of problems. Here's the fixed version.

Here are the errors:

1. Missing DOCTYPE
2. Using numbers to prefix a CSS class
3. Misuse `<br>` to adjust layout
4. Incorrect syntax in media query
5. Alt is missing in images tag
6. Use of obsolete `<center>` tag
7. Incorrect use of `<span>` tag, which is an inline element.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Convite</title>
<style>
body {
    background-image: url("bgg.jpg");   
}
.center {
    margin: auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width : 480px) {
    body {
        background-image: url("bgg.jpg"); /* this line is redundant */
        background-size: cover;
    }

    .foo1 {
        height:300px;
        width:480px;
    }  
    .foo2 {
        height:107px;
        width:480px;
    }
    .foo3 {
        height:34px;
        width:480px;
    }
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="center">
        <div class="foo1"><img src="1.png" alt="" /></div>
        <div class="foo2"><img src="2.png" alt="" /></div>
        <div class="foo3"><img src="3.png" alt="" /></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Last, if you want to make responsive websites, please do not specify fixed height and width.

Comment: Raptor, really thank for your support! The result as that: https://prnt.sc/j8sfcp in desktop and http://prntscr.com/j8sfmp for mobile. What is going on? =(

Comment: Seems you have other codes that interfere your result. If you're confused, please try to use a responsive framework like Bootstrap 4.